# Multiple keyboard shortcuts for setShortcut

Tags: c++, qt

I was wondering if anyone knows how to set up multiple shortcuts for one button.  For example I have a QPushButton that I want to be linked to the Return key and the Enter key (keyboard and number pad).

If in designer I put in the shortcut field:

```
Return, Enter
```

only the Enter responds, not the Return.

I have also tried to just set the Return in designer and in my source code I put in:

```
ui.searchButton->setShortcut( tr("Enter") );
```

This also seems to only respond to Enter (number pad) not Return (keyboard).

Does anyone know how to set more than one shortcut to a QPushButton?  FYI I'm using Qt4.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a little workaround but you could use a QAction set multiple [shortcuts on it](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#setShortcuts) and connect it to your QPushButton. (Similar you could create multiple QShortcut objects and connect them to the button.)

Answer (score 3):

As a qt noob, I was searching for a way to add multiple shortcuts to one button. The answers here were helpful, but I still had to struggle a bit to actually put all of the pieces together. So I thought I would post the full answer here to, hopefully, help other noobs who come after me.

I apologize that this is written in PyQt, but I believe it will convey the idea.

```
# Create and setup a "Find Next" button
find_next_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("      Find &Next")
# setupButton is a small custom method to streamline setting up many buttons. See below.
setupButton(find_next_btn, 150, "Icons/arrow_right_cr.png", 30, 20, "RTL")
find_next_btn.setToolTip("Search DOWN the tree")
find_next_btn.clicked.connect(find_next)
# find_next is the method executed when the button is pressed

# Create an action for the additional shortcuts. Alt+N is already set
# by "&" in "Find &Next"
find_next_ret_act = QtGui.QAction(self, triggered=find_next_btn.animateClick)
find_next_ret_act.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Return"))

find_next_enter_act = QtGui.QAction(self, triggered=find_next_btn.animateClick)
find_next_enter_act.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Enter"))

# Now add (connect) these actions to the push button
find_next_btn.addActions([find_next_ret_act, find_next_enter_act])


# A method to streamline setting up multiple buttons
def setupButton(button, btn_w, image=None, icon_w=None, icon_h=None, layout_dir=None):
    button.setFixedWidth(btn_w)
    if image != None:            
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(image))
        button.setIcon(icon)
    if icon_w != None:
        button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(icon_w, icon_h))
    if layout_dir == "RTL":
        find_next_btn.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
```

Here is the resulting button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb5Mh.png (as a noob, I am not allowed to embed pictures directly into the post.)

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with QtCreator so here are 2 code solutions I would have for this problem.

---

**1.**
For those cases I overwrite the `keyPressEvent` (e.g. of your main window or where you want the shortcut to be).

Header:

```
protected:
    virtual void keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent* e );
```

Source:

```
void main_window::keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent* e )
{
    switch( e->key() )
    {
    case Qt::Key_Enter:
    case Qt::Key_Return:
        // do what you want, for example:
        QMessageBox::information( this,
            "Success",
            "Let me guess, you pressed the return key or the enter key." );
        break;
    default:
        ;
    }

    QMainWindow::keyPressEvent( e );
}
```

---

**2.**
I think it is also possible to create and connect multiple [QShortcut](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qshortcut.html) ojects.
Just create all the shortcuts you need and connect their `activated`-Signal to a slot of the object which you want to receive the shortcut.